# SQL Statement Meaning

Tags: sql

Can someone tell me what this SQL statement is doing? Break it down as to what each part of the statement is doing.

```sql
convert(char(11),(field name 1 + right('0' + cast(field name 2 as varchar(2),2))
```

Comment: Surely, you are able to lookup documentation on these functions without our help?

Comment: really? here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_sqlserver.asp

Find the function click on it and read what it does.

Comment: @Markov: except maybe not _that_ site. But rather an official documentation of the database which he actually uses.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this statement is generating a syntax error due to the `cast()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
convert(char(11),(field_name_1 + right('0' + cast(field_name_2 as varchar(2),2))
```

`convert()` (documentation https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx):
Tells the sql server to convert the value in the second parameter to the type given in the first parameter.

`char(11)`:
Tells the sql server that the value behind the command needs to become a character field type, of a maximum length of 11 characters.

after the comma we have the following

```
(field_name_1 + right('0' + cast(field_name_2 as varchar(2),2)
```

`field_name_1` corresponds to the field on the table you're reading. It will get the value of that field and put it there.

`+` means append string. Append the value that follows after the `+` to the value  before the `+`
for example

```
 'foo' + 'bar' =  'foobar'
 'foo' + 'baz =   'foobaz'
```

So in this case whatever follows behind the `+` should be appended tot he value of `field_name_1`

`right` is a function, get N characters starting from the end of the string(documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql)
within this function a lot happens. But the first part before the comma `'0' + cast(field_name_2 as varchar(2)` is the string `right` is called upon, and the `2` is the number of characters to select from it, starting from the end.

So if you have the following values fed into right

> 013
>    03
>    044

you'll end up with

> 13
>    03
>    44

Now we have this part:

```
'0' + cast(field_name_2 as varchar(2)`
```

`'0'` is a string literal. This is just a string, of length one, that contains the character `0`

`+` means append string. Append the value that follows after the `+` to the value  before the `+`
So in this case, anything that follows the `+` will be appended to `0`.
example:

```
'0' + 'foo' = '0foo'
'0' + '1'   = '01'
```

`cast(field_name_2 as varchar(2))`

In your code you're actually missing a closing `)` here, might cause you some trouble.

Basically what it does it takes the value of `field_name_2` which is probably of the type integer(just guessing) and converts it to the type of varchar, with a maximum length of 2(guessing the number will never exceed 99).
so a number with value of `1` gets turned into a string with the character for the value `1`, namely `'1'`.

```
2  = '2';
33 = '33';
42 = '42';
```

this combined with the previous part would yield

```
'0' + '2' = '02';
'0' + '33' = '033';
'0' + '42' = '042';
```

that will be fed into the `right(value, 2);` which will result in

```
right('02', 2)  = '02';
right('033', 2) = '33';
right('042', 2) = '42';
```

which will be appended to the value of `field_name_1`

```
'foobar' + '02' = 'foobar02';
```

which is then converted in a character type string value of maximum 11 characters long.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I needed.  I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: When an answer has helped you, or has been useful, you can upvote it(the arrow up) as an idication that it's been useful. If it has been the thing you're looking for or has solved your specific problem you can accept it(the checkmark under the upvote/downvote arrows). If an answer is low quality, off topic, not useful to your problem you can downvote it.